# [C#][WPF] After modifying the selected item of datagrid, it is no longer updated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

I'm new to C# and WPF recently.
I fell into a difficult problem for me.

After editing the selected item in the datagrid, the selected item is no longer updated at all.
I use custom class and binding it's member variable to datagrid.

(1) MyCustomCalss

```
public class DualString : IComparable
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public string Origin { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get { return string.Format("{0}({1})", Value, Origin); } }

    public DualString()
    {
        Value = null;
        Origin = null;
    }

    public void Set(string value, string origin)
    {
        Value = value?.Trim();
        Origin = origin?.Trim();
    }
}
```

(2) DataGrid definition in xaml.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_tag" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_tag_SelectionChanged" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" Header="Tag" Width="176"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="datagrid_tag_menu_modify" Header="Modify Tag" Click="datagrid_tag_menu_modify_Click"  />                        
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

(3) ItemSources was set by code, like below. Note that OhterList is used in another DataGrid.

```
private ObservableCollection<DualString> _TagList = new ObservableCollection<DualString>();
private ICollectionView _DataGridViewTag;

foreach (DualString tag in OtherList)
    _TagList.Add(tag);

_DataGridViewTag = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_TagList);
dataGrid_tag.ItemsSource = _DataGridViewTag;
```

(4) code is very simple, like below.

```
private void datagrid_tag_menu_modify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DualString selectedTag = dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem as DualString;
    selectedTag.Set("testValue", "testOrigin");
    _DataGridViewTag?.Refresh();
}
```

The first time I execute datagrid_tag_menu_modify_Click, dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem returns exactly correct instance. However, once I have modified the it, the dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem no longer changes at all.

I've no idea why this symptom is happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer changes at all"? Why should it change?

Comment: BTW: no need for `Refresh()` if you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your DualStrig class.

Comment: It means that whenever I select other row in dataGrid_tag (in application UI), dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem always returns only the item that was initially selected.

Comment: Did you consider that a DataGrid may have multiple selected items and `SelectedItem` will only return the first one?

Comment: Yes, of course. I select only one row, it always returns same instance before modifying.

Comment: I tested it with the code you provided (after fixing several compilation errors)  and could not reproduce - SelectedItem works just fine. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter I found a solution myself. It is caused by multi-selection as you mentioned. After modifying item of item source, it seems that DataGrid holds the first selection item forever in it's SelectedItems list. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. It is caused by multi-selection. After modifying item of item source, it seems that DataGrid holds the first selection item forever in it's SelectedItems list. I execute UnselectAll() before modifying item, then the problem went away.

```
private void datagrid_tag_menu_modify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DualString selectedTag = dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem as DualString;
    
    // execute UnselectAll() before modifying item.
    dataGrid_tag.UnselectAll();
    
    selectedTag.Set("testValue", "testOrigin");

    // re-select item.
    dataGrid_tag.SelectedItem = selectedTag;
    _DataGridViewTag?.Refresh();
}
```